# How to make lambdas work with std::nullopt

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, return-type-deduction

### Background

I have a series of lambdas that perform different checks on the captured variables and return `std::nullopt` if the check failed. `return std::nullopt` is the first return statement. Then, if the check succeeded, they go on and compute the value.

### Problem

The types of return expressions are not consistent, e.g. `std::nullopt_t` cannot be converted to `std::optional<T>`, even though the other way around works. In particular, I'd like the following code to compile and run, printing 2:

```
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <optional>

int x = 3;

auto lambda = [](){
    if (x == 2)
        return std::nullopt;

    return std::optional(2);
};

#include <iostream>

int main () {
    using return_type = std::invoke_result_t<decltype(lambda)>;
    static_assert(std::is_same<return_type, std::optional<int>>{}, 
                  "return type is still std::nullopt_t");

    std::cout << lambda().value() << '\n';
}
```

[Wandbox Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WhdsYtWDWKH9OP86).

### Thoughts

I believe that I need to use `std::common_type<Args...>` somewhere, but I can neither enforce presence of it or deduce `Args`, as it might require language support.

Comment: `std::optional<int> result{}; if(2 != x) { result.emplace(2); } return result;`

Comment: @VTT, wow, I didn't think about it. That makes it somewhat better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using template type deduction to infer the return type of the lambda, why not explicitly specify that return type?

```
auto lambda = []() -> std::optional<int> {
    if (x == 2)
        return std::nullopt;

    return 2;
};
```

`std::common_type` is commonly with templates, which you don't have.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically insert `std::common_type`? I believe that that would be a good change to the language, but I'm unsure if something will get broken.

Comment: @Incomputable I think the committee decided against that on purpose. And with good cause IMO; we don't allow type mismatches in template argument deduction either, neither should we here.

Comment: @Incomputable I mean you could do [this](https://godbolt.org/g/ahBcfD), but no, there is no language way to do that.

Comment: @BaummitAugen, I see your point. Thanks, I got the underlying question answered. I guess I'll either need to choose trailing type or specify the return type manually.

Comment: @BaummitAugen They could apply the rule of operator `?:`. I understand the rationale behind forbidding type mismatches in template argument deduction, but here I'd really like to see the original discussion that throw this option away (if there was one) ;)

Comment: @Holt They could do that directly only for exactly two return statements (or two involved types? already getting murky), and maybe extend the rules in some way to handle arbitrary amounts of types. But your idea might just as well be applied to template argument deduction, which `auto` follows quite closely semantically. The fact that it doesn't work that way is most certainly reason enough for the committee, although I don't have any links handy right now.

Comment: @Holt I find `?:` rules to be too complicated for what it does. Not at all in favor.

Comment: @PasserBy I find a lot of C++ rules too complicat4ed for what they do, but I see your point. ;) Whatever the actual rules, I think deducting return type from multiple `return` statements should be allowed (maybe with conservative rules).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to stick with a single return statement and explicitly specified result type without using nullopt at all. It looks somewhat misleading when a function returns either an integer or a nullopt. Especially if the function was longer. Also if value type was something with an explicit constructor then use of `emplace` allows to avoid typing value type name again.

```
auto lambda = []()
{
    std::optional<int> result{};
    if(2 != x)
    {
        result.emplace(2);
    }
    return result;
};
```

Comment: @Incomputable It actually turned out to be even more misleading than I thought...

Comment: If you have a very long lambda you are doing something wrong :)